# I get error : 06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s" *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new in oracle . I have three table . I want insert to table tbl_ledger_branch from join tbl_ledger , tbl_ledger_input
my code is :

```
DECLARE 
STARTDATE DATE := MIN (EFF_DATE );
ENDDATE  DATE  := MAX (EFF_DATE ) ;
i DATE ;

BEGIN

for  i  in  SATARTDATE .. ENDDATE  LOOP

insert  into   tbl_ledger_branch (ledger_code , name , depth , parent_code , balance , ref_cur_id , eff_date , ref_branch , cur_balance , number_date ) 

select  a.ledger_code  ,  max( b.name ) name  ,  max(b.depth)  depth  , max(CONCAT(SUBSTR(b.LEDGER_CODE,1,9),'00')) PARENT_CODE  ,  sum(a.balance) balance  ,

i  eff_date , a.ref_branch , a.cur_balance   

from   tbl_ledger_input  a  inner join  tbl_ledger b 

on   a.ledger_code = b.ledger_code

where  eff_date <= i 

group by  a.ref_branch ,a.ref_cur_id ,a.ledger_code  , a.cur_balance ;

END LOOP ;


END ;
```

but I get error :

```
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

please help me .

Comment: You can't use `min()` in the `for ...` syntax, and `a.eff_date` wouldn't mean anything if you could - `a` is part of the query inside that loop, so it's out of scope for the loop itself. But why are you using PL/SQL at all? If you need help doing it in plain SQL then include the table structures, sample data and expected result, plus your attempt at that and what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Alex Poole
Thank you for your explanation. Because according to the logic of the question, it should be inserted in the tree at the 6th level. In your opinion, how should I write the code?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that means. But also look at the full error stack for your code; if your client *only* shows that one message then something is wrong, [it should indicate several errors](https://dbfiddle.uk/bUP_2BuF). (You also can't use dates for a `for` loop, incidentally...) Edit your question to show your data and what you are trying to do, and please explain the logic clearly.

Comment: Other things to note: you didn't end your insert command with a semi-colon `;`. e.g., `... group by a.ref_branch, a.ref_cur_id, a.ledger_code, a.cur_balance;`

Comment: @pmdba I edit my code , but I dont know how I can to declare max(eff_date) , min (eff_date ) please help me . please take a look my code

Comment: `SATARTDATE` is not defined, although there is a definition for `STARTDATE`.

Comment: @sami - even if you could populate startdate and enddate (which you could do with a query), you can't use them like that. The line `for  i  in  STARTDATE .. ENDDATE  LOO` will throw "PLS-00862: The type of the iterand is not compatible with an iteration control."

Comment: @Alex Poole
 thank you very much , finally I can resolve this solution :)

Comment: @Alex Poole linkdin

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data i came up with the below, it is not perfect but atleast you can start with this SQL.

```
    insert into tbl_ledger_branch
      (ledger_code,
       name,
       depth,
       parent_code,
       balance,
       ref_cur_id,
       eff_date,
       ref_branch,
       cur_balance,
       number_date)
      with dates as
       (SELECT max(EFF_DATE) start_date, max(EFF_DATE) end_date
          from tbl_ledger_input a)
      
      select a.ledger_code,
             max(b.name) name,
             max(b.depth) depth,
             max(CONCAT(SUBSTR(b.LEDGER_CODE, 1, 9), '00')) PARENT_CODE,
             sum(a.balance) balance,
             a.ref_cur_id,
             a.eff_date,
             a.ref_branch,
             a.cur_balance,
             a.eff_date
        from tbl_ledger_input a, tbl_ledger b, dates c
       where a.ledger_code = b.ledger_code
         AND a.eff_date >= c.start_date
         AND a.eff_date <= c.end_date
       group by a.ref_branch,
                a.ref_cur_id,
                a.ledger_code,
                a.cur_balance,
                a.eff_date;
```

Comment: thank you a lot , but I want with for  i  in  SATARTDATE .. ENDDATE  LOOP
insert into table tbl_ledger_branch . please help me ..

Comment: how can i use over by partion for this code ?